# Is there a way to do multiple filtering in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, retrofit2

I am creating a podcast app for android. I want to filter list of podcast so I could get Health genre only.However there are about 3 different Health genres. I decided to filter all three of it. Now anytime I run the app,I get an empty list showing.However If I should filter only one health genre, everything works perfect.Here is my code.

suspend fun getHealthPodcast(): List {

```
    val requireGenreHF =Genre("1512", "Health & Fitness","https://itunes.apple.com/gb/genre/id1512")
    val requireGenreAH =Genre("1513", "Alternative Health","https://itunes.apple.com/gb/genre/id1513")
    val requireGenreMH =Genre("1517", "Mental Health","https://itunes.apple.com/gb/genre/id1517")

    val listGenre = listOf(requireGenreHF, requireGenreAH, requireGenreMH)

    val results = itunesRepo?.getHealthPodcast()

    if (results != null && results.isSuccessful) {

        val podcasts = results.body()?.feed?.results

        val filteredData = podcasts?.filter {
            it.genres.containsAll(listGenre)
        }
        if (filteredData != null) {
            return filteredData.map { podcast ->
                itunesPodcastView(podcast)
            }
        }
    }
    return emptyList()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`containsAll()` requires that `genres` contains **all** elements of `listGenre`, so podcast has to be marked as every health genre at the same time. If you wanted to search genres for **any** health one, you can do this:

```
it.genres.any { it in listGenre }
```

Comment: your answer worked like a champ.Thanks once more

Answer (score 2):

Let us dive into your code.

> I am creating a podcast app for android. I want to filter list of podcast so I could get Health genre only.However there are about 3 different Health genres. I decided to filter all three of it. Now anytime I run the app,I get an empty list showing

Now let us see this line

```kotlin
val filteredData = podcasts?.filter {
            it.genres.containsAll(listGenre)
        }
```

If you dive into the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/contains-all.html) of the `containsAll` method. This is what is defined

> Checks if all elements in the specified collection are contained in this collection.

So the thing is it makes sure that it filters elements that have all the specified genres which might not be there and thus you get an empty list.

Now coming to the answer and your solution, what you need is simply or condition

```kotlin
val filteredData = podcasts?.filter {
            it.genres.contains(requireGenreHF) || it.genres.contains(requireGenreAH) || it.genres.contains(requireGenreH)
        }
```

There are many more ways to filter like the `any` call, you can look into it. They are much more refined.

Comment: I did that but did not add the ||. Will add it now thanks mate